# parallax background image on Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i used this code:    background: transparent url("../images/2- TOOR.jpg") no-repeat fixed center top / cover;   in my site .
there is no problem in firefox  but in chrome my code dosen't work good
site address is :http://cms.ghasedaktravel.com

Comment: Please, post your completed code here.

Comment: you should prefix for Chrome

Comment: Try to remove `position:relative;` from `.back `.

Comment: @pegah.a Great. Good luck.